# Creating scrollable wallpaper drawing to the canvas

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, live-wallpaper

Creating a live wallpaper I can set a scrollable wallpaper very easily using:

```
wallpaperManager.SetBitmap(bmpWallpaper)
```

However I would like to draw to the canvas using, for example:

```
Canvas c = SurfaceHolder.LockCanvas();
c.DrawBitmap(bmpWallpaper, 0, 0, null);
SurfaceHolder.UnlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

But this produces a wallpaper that doesn't scroll. How can I produce a scrollable wallpaper using the `Canvas`?